# How to store permanent non static value in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm sorry for this being such a vague question but I'm unsure which keywords to search for. I want to store an external number that I can use to run a schedule php program (that aims to transfer data between databases), but there's different id's and whatnot ... point is I need Laravel to remember one number (that will be the latest id from the other server's DB).

Question is how do I store that value? Creating a table to store that single value fells like a bit overkill. I've been looking into cookies and flash memory, however those are always "for the next request" and I'm not sure what that means and it sounds irrelevant to what I want. I would go as far as declare a global variable with that number but I don't know how.

So, to put my question in simple words I would ask how do I persist a number using Laravel 5 framework

thanks.

Comment: Rather than use an 'ordinary' text file, i would use an `SQLite` database, which is a text file. ;-/ The nice thing about it is that if extra information gets added to it then it can be easily processed with SQL.

Comment: that's a good idea actually. But I don't think I will scale any further than this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about saving your ID to a simple text file on the filesystem?

Something like

```
Storage::disk('local')->put('lastid.txt', '165');
```

Take a look at http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem